# How to use service class object in interceptor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using this interceptor for catching errors and pass them to API for logging errors.

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      let http: HttpClient;
      var userService: UsersService;
      userService = new UsersService(http);
      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let errorMessage = '';
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
              errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
            } else {
              errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
            }
            alert(errorMessage);
            userService.errorlog(errorMessage).subscribe();
            return throwError(errorMessage);
          })
        );
    }
}
```

but there is a problem when there is an error occurred then there error with userService that:"Cannot read property 'errorlog' of undefined" .
i think that is because we have not initialized the UserService object but if we init userServe then we also have pass httpClient object. So I am confused about how to subscribe to that service method for transfer the error details to API.

Comment: You should be using Dependency Injection mechanism and put `UsersService` in constructor of your interceptor

Comment: Please also show the constructor of your interceptor.

Comment: Further reading (on how to inject a service): https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: @AlexBiro  if i make the constructor of the interceptor with a parameter of service class then there is error ="Can't resolve all parameters for HttpErrorInterceptor: (?)."
If I make that parameter nullable then same previous error repeats ="Cannot read property 'errorlog' of undefined"

Comment: Add `@Injectable()` decorator to your `HttpErrorInterceptor`  class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import Injector in file

```
import { Injectable,, Injector } from '@angular/core';
```

Import the Service that you want to use

```
import { UsersService } from './localfileSystem'
```

Add variable inside the Class for later use

```
public UsersService: UsersService;
```

Add reference in Constructor

```
constructor(
    public inj: Injector,
    
  )
```

inside intercepter

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this. UsersService = this.inj.get(UsersService);


}
```